# highlight rows and columns within two tables in a div

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have 2 tables in a div and I would like to highlight the same row on both tables at the same time. Right now I only managed to get it to highlight columns and rows in 1 table.

(example: If i hover over "Row2 Column3" in `tbl-2`, Row2 in `tbl-1` should be highlighted and viceversa)

Also how do i get it to highlight the `th` tag too?

```
<div class="row">
<div class="span2 pull-left">
    <table class="table table-bordered pull-left" id="compare-tbl-1">
        <thead>
            <th>Column 1</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Row1
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Row2
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Row3
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Row4
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Row5
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<div class="span10 pull-right">
    <table class="table table-bordered" id="compare-tbl-2">
        <thead>
            <th>Column 1</th><th>Column 2</th><th>Column 3</th><th>Column 4</th><th>Column 5</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Row1 Column1</td><td>Row1 Column2</td><td>Row1 Column3</td><td>Row1 Column4</td><td>Row1 Column5</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Row2 Column1</td><td>Row2 Column2</td><td>Row2 Column3</td>    <td>Row2 Column4</td><td>Row2 Column5</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Row3 Column1</td><td>Row3 Column2</td><td>Row3 Column3</td><td>Row3 Column4</td><td>Row3 Column5</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Row4 Column1</td><td>Row4 Column2</td><td>Row4 Column3</td><td>Row4 Column4</td><td>Row4 Column5</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Row5 Column1</td><td>Row5 Column2</td><td>Row5 Column3</td><td>Row5 Column4</td><td>Row5 Column5</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

```
<script>
    $("#compare-tbl-2 td").hover(function() {
            $(this).parents('table').find('td:nth-child(' + ($(this).index() + 1) + ')').
                  add($(this).parent()).addClass('compare-hover');
      },
      function() {
            $(this).parents('table').find('td:nth-child(' + ($(this).index() + 1) + ')').
                  add($(this).parent()).removeClass('compare-hover');
      });
</script>
```

Comment: Is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/markps/Q4tLX/1/) how it's working now?

Comment: @markpsmith yup, exactly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing your script with this:

```
$("#compare-tbl-2 td").hover(function() {
$(this).closest('tr').addClass('compare-hover');
var idx = $(this).closest('tr')[0].sectionRowIndex + 1;

$('#compare-tbl-1').find('tr:nth-child(' + idx + ')').addClass('compare-hover');
  },
  function() {
      $(this).closest('tr').removeClass('compare-hover');
      $('#compare-tbl-1').find('tr').removeClass('compare-hover');
  });
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markps/Q4tLX/7/)

Comment: almost there, when i hover on "row1" in table1, all of row1's in table 2 should be highlighted, and for some reason when i hover on "Row1 Column1" in table 2, "Column 1" in table 1 is highlighted too. other than that it works perfect. here is the code i'm using http://jsfiddle.net/Q4tLX/8/

Comment: By changing the element that the compare-hover class is used on from 'tr' to 'td', Column 1 is no longer highlighted. This works because we're now targetting individual <td> tags instead of the whole <tr>, and Column 1 is in a <th> tag rather than a <td> [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markps/Q4tLX/12/)

Comment: this is a modification to highlight all rows in table 2 when the corresponding table 1 row is hovered over. [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markps/Q4tLX/13/)